# janrain not returning email info

Tags: php, oauth

Using this code, I get no email address returned from ranjain, basic account only. [Tried with google+ and then facebook]

```
$token = htmlspecialchars($_POST["token"]);
$token_url = "https://rpxnow.com/api/v2/auth_info?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&token=".$token;
$token_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($token_url,true));
```

Test Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["stat"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["profile"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (8) {
    ["providerName"]=>
    string(7) "Google+"
    ["identifier"]=>
    string(53) "https://www.google.com/profiles/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(11) "Cxxxxxxxxx"
    ["name"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
      ["formatted"]=>
      string(11) "Cxxxxxxxxx"
      ["givenName"]=>
      string(5) "Cxxxxxx"
      ["familyName"]=>
      string(5) "Txxxxx"
    }
    ["url"]=>
    string(45) "https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["photo"]=>
    string(99) "https://lh5.googleusercontent.comxxxxxxxxx/photo.jpg?sz=400"
    ["googleUserId"]=>
    string(21) "xxxxxxxxxx"
    ["providerSpecifier"]=>
    string(10) "googleplus"
  }
}
```

This url says the basic package includes email:

> https://rpxnow.com/docs/providers#googleplus

This url shows a simplified response for the basic package:

> https://rpxnow.com/relying_parties/x-youraccount-x/setup_tokenurl#steps

which looks like this:

```
{
  'stat': 'ok',
  'profile': {
    'identifier': 'http://user.myopenid.com/',
    'email': 'user@example.com',
    'preferredUsername': 'Joe User'
   }
}
```

Have they dumped their basic support down to unusable levels?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure the permissions are setup correctly to ensure Janrain passes the [`email`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email-scopes) scope when authenticating with Google+.

You can do this by checking the box next to "Email" in the "Configure Providers" section of the Janrain dashboard.

[image: Janrain Dashboard]